# PiecewiseExpand fails to address assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, pattern-matching

PiecewiseExpand seems to ignore more complex assumptions. Here's an example:

`exp = Piecewise[{{1, s[3, 2][t] - xp[2][t] < 0 && s[3, 2][t] - xp[3][t] < 0 && s[3, 5][t] - xp[3][t] > 0}, {2, s[3, 5][t] - xp[3][t] > 0}}, 3]`

Define assumptions that eliminate the first two pieces:

```
$Assumptions = 0 < s[4, 5][t] < s[3, 5][t] < s[2, 5][t] < s[3, 4][t] < s[1, 5][t] < 
 s[2, 4][t] < s[2, 3][t] < s[1, 4][t] < s[1, 3][t] < xp[5][t] < 
 s[1, 2][t] < xp[4][t] < xp[3][t] < xp[2][t] < xp[1][t] < s[5, 4][t] <
  s[5, 3][t] < s[5, 2][t] < s[4, 3][t] < s[5, 1][t] < s[4, 2][t] < 
 s[4, 1][t] < s[3, 2][t] < s[3, 1][t] < s[2, 1][t]
```

These assumptions imply s[3,2][t]>xp[3][t] and s[3,5][t]<xp[3][t] so only the last piece of exp applies. But PiecewiseExpand does not recognize this:

```
PiecewiseExpand[exp]
```

yields no change in exp.

The undocumented option "FullStrengthInference" doesn't help:

```
 PiecewiseExpand[exp, Method -> {"FullStrengthInference" -> True}]
```

yields no change in exp.

Even adding patterns reflecting the assumptions doesn't help:

```
Assuming[(s[a_, b_][t] > xp[b_][t] && s[a_, b_][t] > xp[b_][t] && 
    s[b_, a_][t] < xp[b_][t] && s[b_, a_][t] < xp[a_][t]) /; a > b, 
 PiecewiseExpand[exp]]
```

yields no change in exp.

Similarly

```
Assuming[(s[a_, b_][t] > xp[b_][t] /; 
    a > b) && (s[a_, b_][t] > xp[b_][t] /; 
    a > b) && (s[b_, a_][t] < xp[b_][t] /; 
    a > b) && (s[b_, a_][t] < xp[a_][t] /; a > b), 
 PiecewiseExpand[exp, Method -> {"FullStrengthInference" -> True}]]
```

has no effect.

Indeed, even winnowing down the assumptions doesn't fully resolve the issue:

```
Assuming[s[3, 5][t] < xp[5][t] < xp[3][t] < s[3, 2][t], 
 PiecewiseExpand[exp]]
```

yields two pieces: 2, which requires s[3,5][t] > xp[3][t], and 3.

Most disappointing. Any ideas for overcoming this weakness are most welcome! Must I expand the assumptions into all implied pairwise comparisons? I hope not! And why don't the patterns in Assuming accomplish exactly that?

**Additional Comments**: It seems PiecewiseExpand does not behave as advertised:

```
$Version

(* 13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022) *)

Clear["Global`*"]

$Assumptions = 
  0 < s[4, 5][t] < s[3, 5][t] < s[2, 5][t] < s[3, 4][t] < s[1, 5][t] <
    s[2, 4][t] < s[2, 3][t] < s[1, 4][t] < s[1, 3][t] < xp[5][t] < 
   s[1, 2][t] < xp[4][t] < xp[3][t] < xp[2][t] < xp[1][t] < 
   s[5, 4][t] < s[5, 3][t] < s[5, 2][t] < s[4, 3][t] < s[5, 1][t] < 
   s[4, 2][t] < s[4, 1][t] < s[3, 2][t] < s[3, 1][t] < s[2, 1][t];

exp = Piecewise[{{1, 
    s[3, 2][t] - xp[2][t] < 0 && s[3, 2][t] - xp[3][t] < 0 && 
     s[3, 5][t] - xp[3][t] > 0}, {2, s[3, 5][t] - xp[3][t] > 0}}, 3]

(* Piecewise[{{1,s[3,2][t]-xp[2][t]<0&&s[3,2][t]-xp[3][t]<0&&s[3,5][t]
-xp[3][t]>0},{2,s[3,5][t]-xp[3][t]>0}},3] *)

PiecewiseExpand[exp, Method -> {"ConditionSimplifier" -> Reduce}]

(* Piecewise[{{2,xp[3][t]<s[3,5][t]}},3]*)
```

One expects `ConditionSimplifier -> Reduce` to work as follows:

```
myPiecewiseExpand[args__] := 
  With[{expression = PiecewiseExpand[args]},  
   (* Delete conditions that evaluate to False *)              
   With[{pieces = DeleteCases[First[expression], 
                  {val_, cond_}/;\[Not]Reduce[cond && $Assumptions]]},
       If[Length[pieces] > 0,                             
         Piecewise[pieces,Last[expression]], 
         Last[expression]]]];
```

That gives the expected results:

```
myPiecewiseExpand[exp]

(* 3 *)

$Assumptions = True;
myPiecewiseExpand[exp]

(* Piecewise[{{1, s[3, 2][t] - xp[2][t] < 0 && s[3, 2][t] - xp[3][t] < 0 && s[3, 5][t] - xp[3][t] > 0}, {2, s[3, 5][t] - xp[3][t] > 0}}, 3] *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

$Assumptions = 
  0 < s[4, 5][t] < s[3, 5][t] < s[2, 5][t] < s[3, 4][t] < s[1, 5][t] < 
   s[2, 4][t] < s[2, 3][t] < s[1, 4][t] < s[1, 3][t] < xp[5][t] < s[1, 2][t] <
    xp[4][t] < xp[3][t] < xp[2][t] < xp[1][t] < s[5, 4][t] < s[5, 3][t] < 
   s[5, 2][t] < s[4, 3][t] < s[5, 1][t] < s[4, 2][t] < s[4, 1][t] < 
   s[3, 2][t] < s[3, 1][t] < s[2, 1][t];

exp = Piecewise[{{1, 
    s[3, 2][t] - xp[2][t] < 0 && s[3, 2][t] - xp[3][t] < 0 && 
     s[3, 5][t] - xp[3][t] > 0}, {2, s[3, 5][t] - xp[3][t] > 0}}, 3]

(* Piecewise[{{1, s[3, 2][t] - xp[2][t] < 0 && 
         s[3, 2][t] - xp[3][t] < 0 && 
         s[3, 5][t] - xp[3][t] > 0}, 
     {2, s[3, 5][t] - xp[3][t] > 0}}, 3] *)
```

[`$Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html) only affects functions that use the option [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html)

```
{#, Options[#]} & /@ {Piecewise, PiecewiseExpand, Simplify} // 
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

```
exp // PiecewiseExpand

(* Piecewise[{{2, s[3, 5][t] - xp[3][t] > 0}}, 3] *)

exp // Simplify

(* Piecewise[{{2, s[3, 5][t] > xp[3][t]}}, 3] *)
```

[`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) will always have at least two parts since the default is always included to cover conditions not meeting any of the given conditions.

**EDIT:** `Piecewise` has the attribute `HoldAll`

```
Attributes[Piecewise]

(* {HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected} *)
```

`PiecewiseExpand` does not cause the `Piecewise` to evaluate, it tries to simplify (using `$Assumptions`) the **form** of the `Piecewise`. Separate effort is required to evaluate the `Piecewise`.

```
exp // PiecewiseExpand
```

[image]

```
Assuming[s[3, 5][t] < xp[3][t], exp // PiecewiseExpand]

(* 3 *)
```

or

```
Assuming[s[3, 5][t] < xp[3][t], exp // Simplify]

(* 3 *)
```

Comment: Bob, thanks so much for considering my question. Apologies, I am confused by your answer. The documentation indicates (DollarSign)Assumptions is the default value of Assumptions in PiecewiseExpand. And indeed, setting:

 (DollarSign)Assumptions = 
 s[3, 5][t] < xp[5][t] < xp[3][t] < s[3, 2][t] && 
  s[3, 5][t] < xp[3][t]; 
PiecewiseExpand[exp]
(* 3 *)

yields the correct and desired result: 3.

Comment: See if the edit answers your question.